# Is it possible to have `<pre><code>` on a separate line?

Tags: html

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
<pre><code>
a command
another command
</code></pre>
```

because it looks nicer than having the `<pre><code>` on the same line as the first command. The above text, however puts an empty line before `a command`

```
a command
another command
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: That's because your code starts with a new line character.

Comment: Yes, I know that but is there a character like ``\`` in bash which continues the line (removing the newline character)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The reason is that line breaks are by definition significant in `pre` element content, and the only exception to this is the browser practice of skipping (in parsing) a line break *at the very start* of the element. This is being formalized in HTML5 [parsing rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody) and also described in clause [Restrictions on content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#element-restrictions).

So if you start a `pre` element with the `<code>` tag, the exception does not apply, and a line break becomes part of the element content.

Comment: You should update the link directly to the relevant sections: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#element-restrictions

Comment: I added a link to that section. The parsing rules say the same thing (under “A start tag whose tag name is one of: "pre", "listing"”).

Answer (score 1):

You can *hide* the first, empty line using CSS, but ***I would not recommend that***:

```
pre:first-line { line-height: 0px; }
```

See working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VRV4j/).

Comment: "I would not recommend that"  Agreed, that is uglier than what he is trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

The trick is to use a negative top margin on the `<code>`. In some browsers, this only works well if you also give the `<code>` a display of inline-block.
To make sure the top margin was exactly one line, I also had to set the line-height explicitly. Remember that if you change it, change both values to the same size.

```css
pre.patched code {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:-1.25em;
    line-height:1.25em;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VRV4j/2/).

Comment: @sevenseacat It is a solution. It shows that it's possible, in spite of the accepted answer. And it's an alternative to MarcinJuraszek's answer. But you want it to be elegant as well? Beautiful?

Comment: oh, it's a valid solution, sure. I'd smack anyone that wrote it in an actual app though.